# What time period (in Muggle history) were the makers of Harry Potter attempting to portray?

Tags: harry-potter

I get that generally, wizards don't use 'technology' because it's not necessary, since they can use magic instead. What I am asking is about the *aesthetics* of the Wizarding World, and what Muggle time period it most closely resembles?

A world where people write on parchment using quills and ink, the type of dress, etc. Is it meant to 'feel like' an aesthetic of a 'real' Muggle time period?

I'm happy for answers that are based on what is seen in the movies or what is described in the books.

Comment: I've cleaned up the question a little to try to make it less opinion-based.

Comment: totally opinion based without more concrete evidence, - but I think it's fair to say that rather than resembling a muggle society stuck in time, the (british) Wizard world effectively broke away from a shared culture around the 14/1500's with the implementation of the Statute of Secrecy. At that point they became their own effectively isolated culture that developed naturally from that point on - essentially on a different cultural timeline from the Muggle world

Comment: @NKCampbell I hear what you're saying, but Rowling and/or the producers of the movies can only reference real-world history, so therefore, my question was what were they referring to. I assumed that they had a historical time period in mind that they wanted to make the Wizarding World feel like, and if Rowling / the movie producers did in fact have one in mind, then it wouldn't be opinion based. Otherwise, I could see how it might seem opinion based, but I'm guessing a historian could still analyze it and come up with a rough set of dates when what is portrayed in the WW would be true.

Comment: The wizarding world does seem stuck in the more-or-less pre-renaissance past (15th century, give-or-take). The movies also seem to add a Dickensian touch (19th century). At least one odd anachronism featured in one of the movies (Goblet of Fire) occurs during the Yule Ball (echos of Steve Tyler). The "wizard radio" featured in Deathly Hallows also seems a bit out-of-time for a pre-renaissance culture..

Comment: @AnthonyX Thanks! I guess the other question is to limit it on the other end. When would be the earliest for the technology they DO have (I'm using the word technology very broadly, including pewter cauldrons, ink, wax for candles, etc.)? Thinking about the architecture of the buildings such as the castle would also be interesting.

Comment: @Eli Bel They have cameras and phonographs.

Comment: @EliBel I saw somewhere that the premise of the Harry Potter universe is that where muggles employ science, technology, and medicine, the wizarding world employs magic... except that magic reaches well beyond the limits of muggle technology. So, the two worlds would have diverged at the point where science and technology really started to become a "thing". Technology really begins with fire and the wheel (arguably), science with the ancient Greeks. The renaissance is when a lot of "lost" ancient knowledge was rediscovered, effectively launching modern science and technology.

Comment: The clothing and technology shown in HP are influenced by a variety of different time periods. It may not be possible to pinpoint an exact era from muggle history.

Comment: I think @creative-username has it. Quills, parchment, steam engines, jumpers, doubledecker buses and robes all come from different time periods (and some are romantic imaginings of a time that never existed). Someone could write a very interesting essay on where and when all of these allusions come from and how they fit into the story. But I'm not sure that essay wouldn't fit the constraints of this question or this site.

Answer (score -1):

The designer of the movie states that Hogwarts is dated to the Medevial era:

> Reasoning that Hogwarts would date back to the medieval era, production designer Stuart Craig (The English Patient) fashioned Hogwarts' Great Hall after England's greatest cathedrals. ([source](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/1105-time-cagle.html))

Don't know if that helps, but it's also the general vibe I got from reading the books as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they mean that the castle *itself* dates back to the medieval era, in much the same way that Buckingham Palace dates back to the 1700s.

Comment: @Valorum The question clearly states "aesthetics of the wizarding world" and that answers the question.

Comment: Again, I'm pretty sure that OP meant the aesthetic of the fixtures and fitments, not the walls and floors.